# Integral of complex periodic signal

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Integrating   $e^{j(k-n)\omega t} \, dt$ over the interval $0$ to $T$ where $T$ is the fundamental time period of the sinusoids yields zero when $k$ is not equal to $n$.... ? how?

assume ω is the fundamental frequency equal to $2\pi/T$.

Comment: I'm guessing $\;j=i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ , but what is $\;\omega\;$ ?

Comment: i edited it.. i had used w for omega

Comment: Good, yet you haven't still explained what is $\;\omega\;$ !

Comment: Also: isn't there missing a $\;t\;$ in the exponential's exponent?

Comment: @DonAntonio : $\omega$ is the frequency.

Comment: That's what I supposed, @MichaelHardy...yet the old problem remains: why students pose incomplete questions?

Comment: I think what needs to be said about $\omega$ is that it is real and not $0$.

Comment: Lots of comments so far, and two answers including mine, but so far mine is the only up-vote for the question.

Comment: . . . . and now someone has down-voted the question.  Why?

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question probably had his/her reasons (some of them are utterly incomprehensible to me), @MichaelHardy, yet I wonder why you *had* to remark that *only you* had upvoted the question...

Comment: @DonAntonio : Because I think people often neglect to do that when they ought to.

Comment: "ought to", @MichaelHardy ? In what cases, in your opinion, someone "ought" to upvote a question??

Comment: I think one instance in which a question ought to be up-voted is when it shows that a student or a non-mathematician is trying to understand something in math that is worth trying to understand.

Comment: I can't say what the OP is or isn't, but if I had to bet I'd probably go for student of physics, and those guys need a lot of mathematics. Anyway, your opinion is not mine but I respect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{j\ell\omega t} \,dt
$$
where $\ell$ is a nonzero integer.  If we let $s=t+c$, where $c$ is some real constant, then we have $ds=dt$, and as $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, then $s$ goes from $c$ to $2\pi+c$.  But since the function is periodic, we have
$$
\int_c^{2\pi+c} \cdots\cdots\,ds = \int_0^{2\pi} \cdots\cdots\,ds.
$$
So
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{j\ell\omega t} \,dt = \int_c^{2\pi+c} e^{j\ell\omega(s-c)} \,ds = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{j\ell\omega(s-c)} \,ds = e^{-j\ell\omega c} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{j\ell\omega s} \,ds = e^{-j\ell\omega c} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{j\ell\omega t} \,dt.
$$
The last equality holds because we can rename the bound variable.

Now we have
$$
\text{integral} = (e^{-j\ell\omega c}\cdot\text{same integral}).
$$
If the integral is not $0$, then we can divide both sides by it and get
$$
0 = e^{-j\ell\omega c}.
$$
But this is clearly false, so the integral must be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be you mean

$$\int\limits_0^T e^{i(k-n)wt}dt=\frac i{wt(n-k)}e^{i(k-n)wt}=\left.\frac i{wt(n-k)}e^{wti(k-n)}\right|_0^T=$$

$$=\frac i{wt(n-k)}\left(e^{2\pi i(k-n)}-1\right)=0$$

Check that if you had $\;k=n\;$ then you'd have

$$\int\limits_0^T 1\,dt=T\neq 0$$